# probability of extinction in branching process $\{X_n,n\geq 0\},X_0=1, P(Y=k)=\frac{1}{2^{k+1}},k = 0,1,2, ...$

Tags: statistics, markov-chains, markov-process

> consider the branching process $\{X_n,n\geq 0\},X_0=1,
> > P(Y=k)=\frac{1}{2^{k+1}},k = 0,1,2, ...$
>
> show the pgf of Y is $G(s) = \frac{1}{2-s}$
>
> what is the probability of eventual extinction?
>
> find the pgf for $X_n$.

I've shown the pgf for Y. but when solving $G(s)=s$ the two roots are 0 and 2. if $\pi_0$ is the minimal roots then extinction probality would be $0$, but when i calculated $E(Y) = G'(s=1) = 1$ which indicates extinction. Why is it contradictory?
Also I do i find the pgf of $X_n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac 1 {2-s}=s$ gives $(2-s)s=1$ or $s^{2}-2s+1=0$. This gives $(s-1)^{2}=0$  so $1$ is the only root.

Comment: @smaillis $G_n(s)$ (the $n-$th iterate of $G$ is of the form $\frac {a_ns+b_n} {c_n+d_n}$ You can find recurrence realtions between the coefficients to find $G_n(s)$  from which you can write down the distribution of $X_n$.